# Renaming com. package in Android studio fails

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to rename the package in android studio to make it look like 
us.myorganization.myapplication 
from 
com.myorganization.myapplication 
but when I click refactor button on the "com" part of it while deselected "compact middle packages" all it does is replacing all the files from the old package to a new one without renaming the entries in the files so that everything breaks. It results in empty "old" package and a new, . [the broken one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnlin.png)

Comment: why you want to rename package?

Comment: @VasudevVyas I have issues with firebase crashlytics and wrong package name is one of the options why it's not working for me.

Comment: did you try to rename only application id?

Comment: you can use the command ctrl + shift + R it can find and replace the package name